# Running testng with Spring context in Intellij Idea

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, testng

When I run tests in my maven module from cmd I see that Spring context is available for all my tests even when they don't extend `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` and are not annotated with `@ContextConfiguration`.

However, when I run all tests in the test dir from Idea, some of the tests fail with NPE because `@Autowired` fields are not initialized. Most confusing is that, as I said, some tests pass and others don't even though they all don't extend `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` and are not annotated with `@ContextConfiguration` but all require Spring-injected fields in some of the classes. When I run tests separately in Idea, they always fail with NPE because there's no Spring injection. I'm new to testng and can't understand how the Suites are created and run with Spring context.

By the way, we tried it on Ubuntu machine, and the behaviour is not the same. Separate tests failed, but running the package succeeded without injection-related NPE issues.

Anyone encountered anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to revolve around IntelliJ/testNG not processing 'groups' correctly. If a class "A" defines an autowired object, the @beforeGroups method in that class cannot use that object. But a different class "B" that extends class "A", and "B" has a @Test that uses the autowired object, then "B" can use the object (which is defined in "A", where it doesn't work!!!). Problem does not occur in Eclipse or with a Maven goal where surefire controls testNG.

The workaround for IntelliJ is to run an entire suite, instead of just a method or class. If we create a new suite file and strip out all the other classes, then we can run just one class.

Comment: It might be better to delete this answer and create a new question, especially since the original question is more than two years old, you might not ever get a response.

Comment: @PaulT. Yeah, I probably should have. Happened to stumble across a solution / workaround today, so I've edited my response to be more of an answer than a followup question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See these issues in YouTrack

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135384

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125775

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110703

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-111084